# how to write mm/dd/yyyy date format for input field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have to format a date in an input textbox in javascript or angular, and I am facing an issue in my code.

HTML:

```
<input  type="text" class="form-control" name="dateOfBirth" ng-model="dob" placeholder="Birthday(MM/DD/YYYY)" ng-required="true" ng-change="change()" maxlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" dob-format>
```

JS:

```
 vm.change = function (e) {
    if (vm.dob) {
        var dobLen = vm.dob.length;
        if (dobLen === 2 || dobLen === 5)
            vm.dob = vm.dob + "/";
    }
};
```

If I type "6"(month) instead of "06", it must automatically change to "06", here I am facing an issue where the forward slash will come when I type two letters and the backspace is not working. So anyone please help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is vm here?

Comment: is that scope ?

Comment: @lalithkumar yes it is scope variable like var vm=this

Comment: You could probably make the date check on blur (instead of doing it in change). This way you could use `Date.parse` on the whole string and then use angular filters to format the date

Comment: @Phugo can you please explain,how to do using ng-blur?

Answer (score 1):

Change accordingly in change event.

```
Regex_replace('0' + Replace([Starting Date], '/', '/0'), '0*(\d\d)/0*(\d\d)/0*(\d\d)', '20$3-$1-$2')
```

Comment: what is this?can you just explain?

Comment: @AWE sorry I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static getDateForm_german(date: Date): string {
    let filter = {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit'
    };
    return date.toLocaleString('de-DE', filter);  
    // returns like 30.02.1999 for 1999-02-30
}
```

i know it is not the format you are looking for, and it is typescript. but i think you are looking for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
          app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
              vm=$scope;
               vm.change = function (e) {
    if (vm.dob) {
        var dobLen = vm.dob.length;
        if (dobLen === 2 || dobLen === 5)
            vm.dob = vm.dob + "/";
    }
};
          }]);
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
        <input  type="text" class="form-control" name="dateOfBirth" ng-model="dob" placeholder="Birthday(MM/DD/YYYY)" ng-required="true" ng-change="change()" maxlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" dob-format>
     </div>
```

This is working like charm for me.

Comment: This is the remember to accept the answer if appropriate @pbsbr

Answer (score 0):

A mixture of the `pattern` attribute and some `onchange` formatting can fix this:

```js
var inp = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
inp.pattern = "\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d";
inp.placeholder = "YY/MM/DD";
inp.required = true;

function formatDate(evt) {
  var val = inp
    .value
    .toString().split("/")
    .map(function(a) {
      if (a.length == 1) {
        return "0" + a;
      }
      return a;
    })
    .join("/");
  if (/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d/.test(val)) {
    inp.value = val;
  }
}
inp.onchange = formatDate;
```

Comment: This does nothing at all for formatting and or validation.